# Error when start a new project in cordova-ionic in Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

I have the next problem, i have installed cordova version
7.0.1 , node version 4.2.6 , but i have this error if all is correct in when  instal Node JS and Cordova y ionic?

why I have this problem?

```
sommer@sommer-AO532h:~$ cordova -v
7.0.1
sommer@sommer-AO532h:~$ 
sommer@sommer-AO532h:~$ ionic -v
ERR: Your Node.js version is v4.2.6. Please update to the latest Node 6 LTS version (or latest Node).
sommer@sommer-AO532h:~$ node -v
v4.2.6
sommer@sommer-AO532h:~$ ionic start todo blank --type ionic1
ERR: Your Node.js version is v4.2.6. Please update to the latest Node 6 LTS version (or latest Node).
sommer@sommer-AO532h:~$
```

Comment: Please read error messages! You have an outdated node version. Just install the newest one.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Requirements](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/blob/master/README.md#requirements) Section from ionic-cli [GitHub Page](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli) -

> - Node 6 LTS (latest)
> - npm 3+

So you need Node 6 LTS to use   [`ionic-cli`](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli), The Ionic command line interface (CLI) i.e the one that you are using.

So update it first and then use `ionic-cli`.